# How to use mergeWith with Subjects in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs

**Goal:** A Combined Filter with 3 Inputs to filter some list

**Restrictions:**

- The User should not be forced to complete all available filters to submit
- The first submit should happen once the user inputs
- Different Inputs are combined once there is more than one

**My Take:**
I send the input data from the 3 different  input components to Subjects in a Service that should act as event emitter between input and the actual combination, to be able to reuse and cherry pick different inputs as needed

```
export class FilterInputStoreService {
  public selectedTypesHandler = new Subject<string>();
  public selectedPrivacyOptionsHandler = new Subject<boolean>();
  public searchInputHandler = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor() {}
}
```

In the filter combination component i try to "listen" to if a subject sends something and combine it with the rest using mergeWith.

```
this.filterInputStore.selectedTypesHandler
    .mergeWith(this.filterInputStore.searchInputHandler, this.filterInputStore.selectedCurrenciesHandler )
    .map(() => {
       this.combinedDataObject = {
       Here i combine the values, doesnt matter for the question
        };
         }),
        tap(() => {
          this.filterService.newFilterData(this.combinedDataObject);
        })
       )
        .subscribe();
```

**Problem:**

- It Says mergeWith cannot be used with Subjects
- Other operators like
  combineLatest dont work because they require to wait until every of
  the sources has an input.
- Cant use Behaviorsubject because that emits an initial value which is null, causing the filter to crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mergeWith`, like `merge` works seamlessly with Subjects.

Example :

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

const s1 = new Subject<string>();
const s2 = new Subject<string>();
const s3 = new Subject<string>();

s1.pipe(mergeWith(s2, s3)).subscribe(console.log);


s1.next('1')
s2.next('12')
s3.next('123')

// output 1, 12, 123.
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bjrytm?file=index.ts)

Comment: I get the error "mergewith is not available for the type "Subject<string>" "

Comment: which version on rxjs are you using ? Please share a reproducible example on stackblite.

Comment: Reading your example I just realized i forgot the .pipe() , now it works. Thank you